# Clone a Xen instance but add memory to it

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have a machine that has a few Xen instances running on it. I'd like to clone one of them but allocate more RAM to the new clone. How can I do this?

Comment: Man you guys are rough with the voting

Comment: Lucas found the answer in the documentation within **3 minutes** of your question hitting the site, and I - with NO Xen experience - was able to intuit the same and found similar references with a simple Google search for `xen memory size`. Sorry if it seems harsh, but I consider that the essence of "does not show any research effort". You need to spend at least a few minutes with [the duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) known as Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By cloning it and changing its template file before booting?

You will have to look at this entry:

```
<memory>262144</memory>
```

Have a look at [this xen pdf guide](http://xen.org/files/XenCloud/guest.pdf).